# Grouping spaces in Forsyth-Edwards notation

Tags: python, string

In [Forsyth-Edwards notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation), I have a string like this:

```
string = rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/********/********/********/********/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR
```

where `*` represents an empty space.
It needs to be notated like this:

```
string = rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR
```

where the '8' represents the number of empty spaces.

For example, given a string like this:

```
string = rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/*r*****/****p***/********/*******/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR
```

The result should be:

```
string = rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/1r6/4p3/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR
```

Can anyone help me in the right direction?

Comment: If I understand the notation correctly, your second example is wrong - it looks like you're missing a square in a the third and sixth ranks. And the desired output doesn't match the input either; you have `1r7` instead of `1r5` (which corresponds to what you wrote) or `1r6` (which it should be). Again, if I understand the notation correctly, which I'm not sure I do.

Comment: @DavidZ - I suspect that's just a made-up value the OP is trying to run the substitutions on.  The last example doesn't describe a legal board position anyway, since there are 3 black rooks and 9 black pawns on the board, with the extra pieces having already moved, but white having not yet moved at all.

Comment: I see, you're right. I made a typo. the correct one must be 1r6 i corrected it. And yes it's a made up value for example. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to mind is [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). A regex that matches a sequence of spaces is just `\s+`, and you can use [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) or the [`sub()` method of a compiled pattern](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.regex.sub) to replace matches (i.e. sequences of spaces) with whatever you like. You can give `sub()` a function as the replacement value, and that function will be called on each [match object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects) to compute the actual replacement.

```
re.sub(r'\s+', lambda m: str(m.end() - m.start()), string)
```

Comment: You can just use `len` on the match rather than doing the arithmetic yourself.

Comment: No, match objects don't have a `__len__()` method. (Believe me, I checked.)

Comment: I meant on the first group, as per my answer.

Comment: Yes, but there's no particular advantage in doing that over subtracting the end and start positions.

Comment: It's a matter of opinion, but I think the intent is clearer if  you use `len`, and doing your own arithmetic is just another way of introducing a bug.

Comment: And I think the opposite. Calling `group()` is just as much a way of introducing a bug, in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Without regex, you may achieve the same result using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) with *list comprehension* expression as:

```
from itertools import groupby, chain
s = 'rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/*r*****/****p***/********/*******/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR'

new_str = ''.join(chain(*[[str(len(list(j)))] if i else list(j) \     
                      for i, j in groupby(s, lambda x: x=='*')]))
```

Cleaner version of this could be written with explicit `for` loop as:

```
my_string = 'rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/*r*****/****p***/********/*******/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR'
new_list = []

for is_blank, group in groupby(my_string, lambda x: x=='*'):
    temp_list = list(group)
    if is_blank:
        temp_list = [str(len(temp_list))]
    new_list.extend(temp_list)

new_str = ''.join(new_list)
```

Final value hold by `new_str` will be:

```
>>> new_str
'rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/1r5/4p3/8/7/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.sub` and substitute into the string the length of the matches:

```
import re
s = re.sub("\\*+", lambda x: str(len(x.group(0))), s)
```